# Where should I store session code in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2, session-variables

In a Rails app I'm creating, I have some code in my controller that I'm wondering whether it's in the proper place.  The code is fairly insignificant, it stores ids in an array to show 'recently viewed' pages.  It's about 3 lines of code, but I'm thinking to the future, what if this feature expands? I don't want my controller to be bloated.

I could make a module, but in that case where should I store the file?
Is the controller the right place to be doing the session management?
Any suggestions on my code organization?

Thanks

Comment: If you paste the code you're talking about, it may make it easier for folks to give you a good response.

Comment: I thought about it but I was more wondering about the concepts of code/file organization and didn't want people to get bogged down in syntax. Thanks for responding though! This is my first question on StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is specific to the controller, keep it in the controller.

If it applies to all controllers, it goes in ApplicationController.

If it is shared by some controllers and not others, then inherit from a controller that inherits from ApplicationController, or use include/extend or [make a module that extends](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) `ActiveSupport::Concern` (which is what Rails uses internally fairly commonly).

And it's best to keep everything in `app/controllers` or some subdirectory, sub-subdirectory, etc. Rails autoloading depends on the path to match up with the module namespace, so `A::B::C` belongs in `app/controllers/a/b/c.rb`. Don't make it deep like Java, etc. Just have the number of directories/modules you need to keep it organized.

Note: though controllers aren't as problematic to have in their own modules, in my experience your models should stay in the root, like `app/models`, or you'll have problems.

I'd also avoid storing too much in session if you can help it. Store in the DB (or long-life cookies, if it is browser-environment specific) instead. For example- if someone logs out and they were looking at one record, they might want to log back in later and have a list containing the link to that record.

BTW- you weren't asking and probably already have the code for storing recently visited pages in session, but here are similar questions/answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10813602/178651
- http://www.rorexperts.com/how-to-store-visited-pages-in-session-object-in-rails-t941.html

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks! This was my first question on StackOverflow, and you gave me tons of good Rails advice.